# high frequency app for the Ubuntu smartphone

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch

An app is considered for the Ubuntu smartphone that involves:

1. Monitoring low voltage, compound analog wave forms with a peak frequency component of 4.4 MHz.
2. Uploading faithful digital equivalents in a cloud.
3. Downloading from the cloud processed digital equivalents.
4. Converting the stream of the digital equivalents into faithful, low voltage compound analog wave forms that include a peak frequency component of 4.4 MHz.

My question is: can the Ubuntu smartphone carry out all the above activities? If not, then which of the above activities can it carry out?

I'm looking forward to your comments.

Answer (score 1):

2 & 3 would be trivial as Qt has very good APIs for dealing with this kind of thing.

1 & 4 would require extra A/D and D/A hardware interfaced to the phone somehow. This presents a problem as there are multiple ways of interfacing and every phone supports a different subset of these standards. Assuming your phone supports USB-OTG then this would be quite easy. You would simply communicate with the hardware using libusb, much as you would on a normal PC.